# Trouble with os.chroot()

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I tried running the following script and it works fine but I am not getting the expected result:

```
import os,sys
os.system("mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt")
os.system("lsblk")
os.system("mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc")
os.system("mount --bind /home /mnt/home")
os.system("mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev")
os.system("mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys")
os.chroot("/mnt")
os.system("pwd")
os.system("lsblk")
```

This is because when I do pwd after os.chroot("/mnt"), I am not inside the "/mnt" directory. However, when I run the following code directly into Linux terminal with shell commands(without using a python script), I am getting my expected result.

Now my question is, why can't I go into the /mnt directory using os.chroot("/mnt"). How can I achieve this using os.chroot(using python script) ?

Comment: `os.chroot("/mnt")` does not "go into the `/mnt` directory", by which I guess you mean change the pwd to `/mnt`. It only changes the process' root directory. Is it `os.chdir()` you want, not `os.chroot()`?

Comment: Ok.how can I constrain my files within the chroot directory tree using a python command instead of os.chroot..I would like to do Yum update & build a kernal on my "/mnt"..Therefore I need a command to duplicate the functionality of "chroot command using shell" by using a python command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's [`os.chroot`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chroot) is a raw wrapper around the [`chroot(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chroot) system call.  As stated in the system call documentation:

> This call does not change the current working directory, so that after the call '.' can be outside the tree rooted at '/'. In particular, the superuser can escape from a "chroot jail" by doing:
>
> ```
> mkdir foo; chroot foo; cd ..
> ```
>
> This call does not close open file descriptors, and such file descriptors may allow access to files outside the chroot tree.

You need to explicitly change the current working directory yourself, e.g. `os.chdir('/')` to move into the new root.

You're seeing different behavior than when running the commands from a shell because the [`chroot(1)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/chroot-invocation.html#chroot-invocation) executable explicitly changes the current working directory to the new root ([source](https://github.com/goj/coreutils/blob/rm-d/src/chroot.c#L205)).

Comment: Ic.Very informative.However how can I constrain my files within the chroot directory tree using a python command instead of os.chroot..I would like to do Yum update & build a kernal on my "/mnt"..Therefore I need a command to duplicate the functionality of "chroot command using shell" by using a python command.

Answer (score 0):

> The method chroot() changes the root directory of the current process
>   to the given path.To use this method, you would need super user
>   privilege.

Source: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chroot.htm

Could it be the root-cause?

As a workaround, you could call `os.system("cd /mnt; mycommand")`

Comment: Nope..I tried running it as a su and it didnt solve the problem..Thanks :)

Comment: As a workaround, you could call `os.system("cd /mnt; mycommand")`

Comment: yup.Im aware of the cd command..however I need to run this using chroot command as I dont want to access files and commands outside that environmental directory(outside /mnt) tree.